# How to pass data to Plots OHLC function in Julia

Tags: julia, back-testing, plots.jl, ohlc

I'm having an issue figuring out how to get data from a dataframe in this format:
[image]

These are the types that get printed from each column:

```
DataType[Any, Any, Any, Any, Any]
```

This is the error i'm getting and already tried converting the types without success:

```
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching Plots.OHLC(::Vector{Any}, ::Vector{Any}, ::Vector{Any}, ::Vector{Any}, ::Vector{Any})
```

The code tries to get the data from an excel file and plot it into a candlestick chart:

```
using Dates
using XLSX
using Plots
using DataFrames

# Load data from Excel file
data = DataFrame(XLSX.readtable("Janeiro2023.xlsx", "Sheet1"))

# Check data types of columns
println(eltype.(eachcol(data)))

# Extract the columns as arrays
datetime_array = data[!, 1]
open_array = data[!, 2]
high_array = data[!, 3]
low_array = data[!, 4]
close_array = data[!, 5]

# Create an OHLC object from the arrays
ohlc = Plots.OHLC(datetime_array, open_array, high_array, low_array, close_array)

# Plot the candlestick chart
plot(ohlc)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should read your data with `infer_eltypes=true` when reading excel:

```
data = DataFrame(XLSX.readtable("Janeiro2023.xlsx", "Sheet1"; infer_eltypes=true))
```

This will set the appropriate types. However (depending on your input data) the date column will still be a string and you will need to parse it `using Dates`:

```
data.Data .= DateTime.(data.Data, dateformat"yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:SS")
```

Comment: The infer_eltypes attribute successfully converted the columns to Float64 but the Data column which should be a Date still not passing. Any idea?

ERROR: MethodError: no method matching Int64(::Vector{Dates.DateTime})

Comment: In that case just convert it it string before converting to date so the code will be: `data.Data .= DateTime.(string.(data.Data), dateformat"yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:SS")`